# How Can I Prevent screen recording in my woordpress Site

Tags: wordpress

I have A wordpress Site and i want to Prevent screen recording in the web because I offer
paid courses

wordpress site For Courses .............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................thanks for that>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

Comment: What search terms did you use when tried to find your answer?

Answer (score 0):

In general, if somebody wants to record the screen you can't entirely prevent it.

You can, however, use this Plugin: WP Content Copy Protection & No Right Click
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-content-copy-protector/

It will make it harder and forces anybody who wants to record the content to use 3rd party software to do so.